# Silverlight 4 NewBie Question

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am watching a video from Silverlight.net website about DataForm. There is no source code download, so I am typing in the code as I watch the video. Unfortunately I can't replicate what is shown in the video. there are several issues. I am going to list out only the first 2

1) The presenter shows a simple class inside DataForm that has a icon at the very top of the data form that upon clicking it makes the DataForm editable and a save button appears at the
bottom. I did'nt get the same thing when I ran my code against Silverlight 4 or Silverlight 3

2) Than he goes on to show that if you mark your class [Bindable(false)] you shouldn't see anything in your page. I did that but my form still shows all the properties

I stopped after these 2 issues. If the features being talked about in this video were deprecated in the final release than this video should have been taken off the site.
can anyone help me with this??

Comment: Including a link directly to the video in question would really help.

Comment: 13 questions over a year of membership and not one of them answered to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 0):

There are differences in Silverlight 4 from previous version with the DataForm.  If you are using SL4 then perhaps I can help:

1. Add `CommandButtonsVisibility="All"` to your DataForm XAML.  Explore CommandButtonsVisibility for other options.
2. I have this same problem.  Perhaps someone can shed light on this?